# Microsoft Graph API delta query for channelMessages never returns a deltaLink

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to use delta query to get teams channel messages updates according this documentation: [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-delta?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

This is the request url:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/<teamId>/channels/<channelId>/messages/delta`

However, calling the returned `nextLink`s one after another never returns a `deltaLink`. There're too many pages of results and it causes my app to be throttled before ever getting a `deltaLink` from it.

In other delta query endpoints, `$top` is supported to limit the number of results returned. Usually I'm able to get a `deltaLink` after calling the `nextLink`s once or twice. But `$top` doesn't seem to have an effect in the channel messages endpoint.

So I tried appending another queryString `?odata.maxpagesize=10` to the request instead, and it seemed to work a week ago. I was able to get the `deltaLink` after 2 pages. But it looks like Microsoft might have changed the API and this workaround no longer works.

I also tried adding `Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=10` in my request header according to this documentation: [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-data-web-api)

But the `nextLink` this generates is too long and it gives me this error instead:

*HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.*

Has anyone been able to use this delta for channel messages? Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: $top you can get is 50. In case if you're tracking changes in channel messages incurs a round of one or more delta function calls. If you use any query parameter (other than $deltatoken and $skiptoken), you must specify it in the initial delta request. Microsoft Graph automatically encodes any specified parameters into the token portion of the nextLink or deltaLink URL provided in the response.

Comment: Also to proceed with a round of change tracking, simply copy and apply the nextLink or deltaLink URL returned from the last GET request to the next delta function call for that same calendar view. A deltaLink returned in a response signifies that the current round of change tracking is complete. You can save and use the deltaLink URL when you begin the next round. This approach had worked for me.